# How to fix TF.IDF functions on pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

I'm trying to develop TF.IDF process on pyspark by MapReduce (The platform is Databricks). Since I'm really new to pyspark, Databricks, and to the whole process of MapReduce, I get some syntax problems I don't manage to solve.

Here is the code I try to run:

```py
full_text = sc.wholeTextFiles("/FileStore/tables/full_text.txt", 5) 
number_of_docs = full_text.count()

import re

def tokenize(s):
  return re.split("\\W+", s.lower())

#Tokenize the text
tokenized_text = full_text.map(lambda text,title: (title, tokenize(text)))

#Count Words in each document
term_frequency = tokenized_text.flatMapValues(lambda x: x).countByValue()
term_frequency.items()[:20] # Display 20 lines

document_frequency = tokenized_text.flatMapValues(lambda x: x).distinct()\
                        .map(lambda title,word: (word,title)).countByKey()


document_frequency.items()[:10]

import numpy as np


def tf_idf(number_of_docs, term_frequency, document_frequency):
    result = []
    for key, value in tf.items():
        doc = key[0]
        term = key[1]
        df = document_frequency[term]
        if (df>0):
          tf_idf = float(value)*np.log(number_of_docs/df)

        result.append({"doc":doc, "score":tf_idf, "term":term})
    return result



tf_idf_output = tf_idf(number_of_docs, term_frequency, document_frequency)

tf_idf_output[:10]
```

The problems are on lines:

```
term_frequency = tokenized_text.flatMapValues(lambda x: x).countByValue()
```

```
document_frequency = tokenized_text.flatMapValues(lambda x: x).distinct()\
                        .map(lambda title,word: (word,title)).countByKey()
```

The error: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver)

I'll really appriciate your help here, since I don't know how to solve this :(

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` takes an unary (single argument) function. What you are passing is a binary (two argument) function.

Back in the Python 2 days there `lambdas` supported tuple argument unpacking

```
lambda (text, title): (title, tokenize(text))
```

today you should either index

```
lambda tt: (tt[0], tokenize(tt[1]))
```

or better use a proper function:

```
def tuple_tokenizer(title_and_text):
    title, text = title_and_text
    return title, tokenize(text)
```